# collection-repeat on thumbnail cards and weird margins

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a collection-repeat that iterates through my objects and fills up cards based on them. I have two main questions to complete my job. I have been using 'Thumbnail' cards when using this approach but I am not able to correctly set margins. It basically adds some margin on the left and none on the right nor between different cards (bottom margin). I have tried CSS, but nothing works.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="card" collection-repeat="item in items" item-width="'100%'">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        {{item.eventTitle}}
    </div>

    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <b>{{item.eventHour}}</b><br />{{item.eventText}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I get on the browser (no custom CSS added here), look at the left margin and the unexisting one on the right:

[image]

How can I solve both problems with bottom and right margins?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this appears to be a question about CSS styling; you should consider including that tag in the question, as well as giving a brief listing of the CSS that you tried to use to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As for the tested CSS's, I have not kept them and was desperated... nothing worked for me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there a specific reason you are using collection-repeat? it will limit your styling options.

converting to a simple ng-repeat makes your issues go away http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/PzZVPr

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        {{item}} HEADER
      </div>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        {{item}} BODY..
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Well, I just read that it behaved more efficiently for large lists and supposed it was a substitute for the ng-repeat. I understood it was newer and meant to be used instead of ng...